# Removing links over a specific weight

Tags: python, graph, networkx, edges

I am working with NetworkX and I have built a weighted graph from an adjacency matrix.

Now I would like to remove all the edges which have a weight lower than a specific threshold. How could I identify those links?

Here is how I construct my graph:

```
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(weighted, parallel_edges=False)
```

Now I would like to remove the edges using that condition writing something like the following, but for edges:

```
[node for node, degree in dict(G.degree()).items() if degree > 2]
```

But I get an error when I write `G.edges(i).data()` so I am not able to write the condition to evaluate.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Could you post the code you are having trouble with?

Comment: G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(weighted, parallel_edges=False)

Here is how i construct my graph, now i would like to remove the edges using that condition writing something like: [node for node,degree in dict(G.degree()).items() if degree > 2] but for edges but I get an error when i write G.edges(i).data() so I am not able to write the condition to evaluate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first get the edges with the weights with [`nx.get_edge_attributes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.4/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.get_edge_attributes.html) and then remove the one over a certain weight with [`remove_edges_from`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.remove_edges_from.html?highlight=remove_edges_from#networkx.Graph.remove_edges_from).

Example.

```
>>> weighted = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 3))
>>> G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(weighted, parallel_edges=False)
>>> edge_weights = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
>>> edge_weights
{(0, 0): 2, (0, 2): 8, (0, 1): 4, (1, 1): 1, (1, 2): 4, (2, 2): 2}
>>> G.remove_edges_from((e for e, w in edge_weights.items() if w > 5))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I was looking for!